# VBA Code to Loop Through Columns based on Months Start Date and End Date

Tags: excel, vba

I hope I will be able to explain my Macro requirement well.

Basically it has 5 columns. Col A - Resource Name, Col B - Role, Col C - Month  Start Date, Col D - Month End Date, Col E - Percentage.
Please see the attached Image for a Clear Picture.
![enter image description here][3]

Code: It just prints the First Slot ( First Month - Col E F G )
Attached!

```
Dim A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 As Range
Dim i As Integer
Range("A5").Select

i = ActiveCell.Row
j = ActiveCell.Column

 While (ActiveCell.Value <> "Null")
    Set A1 = Nothing
    Set A2 = Nothing
    Set A3 = Nothing
    Set A4 = Nothing
    Set A5 = Nothing

        If (Range("P" & i).Value) > 0 Then

            Set A1 = Range("C" & i)   ' Role
            Set A2 = Range("A" & i)   ' Resource Name
            Set A3 = UpdateStartDate(i) ' Start Date
            Set A4 = UpdateEndDate(i)   ' End Date
            Set A5 = UpdatePercent(i)   ' Percentage

            Call TransferData(A1, A2, A3, A4, A5)

Else


        End If

 i = i + 1
 Range("A" & i).Select

Wend

End Sub

Sub TransferData(A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 As Range)

Dim i As Integer
i = ActiveCell.Row

    Range("R" & i).Value = A1    'Role
    Range("S" & i).Value = A2    'Resource Name
    Range("T" & i).Value = A3    'Start
    Range("U" & i).Value = A4    'End
    Range("V" & i).Value = A5    'Percentage

End Sub



Function UpdateStartDate(ByVal i As Integer) As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim A3 As Range
Range("E" & i).Select
j = ActiveCell.Column
While (ActiveCell.Value = 0)
    j = j + 4
    Cells(i, j).Select
Wend
Set UpdateStartDate = Cells(2, j)

End Function

Function UpdateEndDate(ByVal i As Integer) As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim A4 As Range
Range("G" & i).Select
j = ActiveCell.Column
While (ActiveCell.Value = 0)
    j = j + 4
    Cells(i, j).Select
Wend
Set UpdateEndDate = Cells(2, j)
End Function

Function UpdatePercent(ByVal i As Integer) As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim A5 As Range
Range("G" & i).Select
j = ActiveCell.Column
While (ActiveCell.Value = 0)
    j = j + 4
    Cells(i, j).Select
Wend
Set UpdatePercent = Cells(i, j)
End Function
```

Comment: Attached Images of the Code! Please Review! Would be Really Grateful :)

Comment: Please, never post code as images. Instead copy - paste as text, select the code and press the '{}' button in the editor to format it as code.

Comment: That should help a bit, but pictures of code cannot be copy/pasted into our own Excel to troubleshoot, and no one is going to spend the time typing all of that in just to try and understand what you are trying to do. Hopefully someone will come along that will be able to spot something that may help you.

Comment: Sorry Guys! I am new to this forum. I apologize for the inconvenience caused. I have posted the code. Please Review!